# Errors after upgrading PHP to 7.4 WordPress

Tags: php, errors

After upgrading PHP to 7.4 FastCGI I'm getting these errors:

> :  fread(): read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=21 Is a directory in
> example.com/wp/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5977

And:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
> (output started at example.com/wp/wp-includes/functions.php:5977) in
> example.com/wp/wp-admin/admin-header.php on line 9

I have 3 plugins all disabled.

Comment: Is your copy of WP up to date and unmodified? That line is a comment in the latest version of that file, not an `fread` call https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php#L5977

Comment: This has an official bug report at https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/49979, I recommend registering on WP Trac and leaving feedback indicating your setup and that you too have that issue

Comment: @TomJNowell It's been a few months but I think it has to this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hashed-ids/. The plugin works fine in normal wordpress but causes errors in Network Wordpress (WPMU).

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a theme problem, since you have all plugins disabled. The theme has some error, possibly some extra spaces at the top of a file.

I'd change to one of the 'Twenty' themes and see if the problem stops. If so, contact your theme's support area.

If problem persists with one of the "Twenty" themes active, then I'd try a re-install/re-update of the WP core code, using the Admin, Updates screen.

Comment: I have the plugins disabled but one of them was causing the errors! I removed the folder from the plugin directory and the errors went away

Comment: @1.21gigawatts Which plugin?

Comment: It's been a few months but I think it has to do with https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hashed-ids/. The plugin works fine in normal WP install but in Network install it throws errors.